# Identifying a round connector with four pins and screwable housing

Tags: connector, identification, plug

This cable was in use carrying both power and data to a simple push-button panel previously.

It has three small and one big female pin.

[image]

Close-up photo of the front, with logo.
[image]

Comment: It looks like a power DIN plug, but I've drawn a blank finding that pin configuration so far; possibly the internet is broken. The power connector on my little Behringer mixer sitting about two feet away seems to have the same shell, but three pin without the big one.

Comment: I suspect it's some flavor of 38999 connector.

Comment: If you have seen one military connector - you can Imagen them all. [Here is a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Military_connector_specifications) of many of them.

Comment: It looks like a normal 3 terminal power connector with an extra pin for misc function.

Comment: There is a rather indistinct logo between the pins. A better photo may thelp identify the manufacturer via that logo.

Comment: What country was the end product made in? The knurling and plating looks pretty crappy.

Comment: Added a close-up photo of the front, with a decent view of the logo. The closest match I've seen thus far are 4-pin CB plugs, but they don't match with the three small and single large pin. No clue where it was originally made.

Answer (score 1):

The questioned connector shares similar characteristics, yet not all, to the 4-Pin XLR plugs that I have noticed Philmore Datak had previously supplied in the past.

[image: philmore]

Comment: wow, a downvote for that?

Comment: Here, I added an upvote to even it out. While this wasn't the answer, it was still useful information.

Comment: FWIW - the connector that you show is NOT a XLR connector.

Comment: @DwayneReid  http://www.hspcon.com/product/f/mike-connector/f-2201.php

Answer (score 0):

I guess these are Loudspeaker Connectors, with usually metal housing.

Amphenol is Audio High Power Connectors where : EP Series feature precision-machined and high-current contacts, as well as a diecast metal housing.

Here is the datasheet :

[EP-4-11PB - Amphenol Datasheet](http://pdf.datasheet.online/datasheets-1/amphenol/EP-4-11PB.pdf)

Comment: It's obviously not that.   The products you link do their keying with the pattern of the pins, while the connector asked about does it by having one larger than the others.